# C++ printing floating point numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point, cout

Is there a single best way to print floats (i'm using long doubles)? I have tried a few ways but none of them seems to work for all type of numbers.

Let me illustrate.

I have three print statements.

```
print(M_PI); // from cmath
print(1.234);
print(1.234e-10);
```

These are the results for a few implementations of print(const long double &n):

SIMPLE COUT

```
cout << n << endl;

3.14159 // not good
1.234 // good
1.234e-10 // good
```

COUT WITH PRECISION

```
cout.precision(numeric_limits<long double>::digits10);
cout << n << endl;

3.14159265358979312 // good
1.23399999999999999 // bad
1.23400000000000008e-10 // not good
```

COUT WITH FIXED PRECISION

```
cout.precision(numeric_limits<long double>::digits10);
cout << fixed << n << endl;

3.141592653589793116 // good
1.233999999999999986 // bad
0.000000000123400000 // not good
```

There are a couple other possibilities with 'scientific' instead of fixed but that's cleary not desirable.

Comment: I can't tell how you're deciding what's good and what's bad. The "bad" ones with lots of `9`s or `0`s are simply caused by imprecision in floating point representations.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) - must read.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze You know what, that advice is so good and it's been well over a year since I read that, I think I'll go read it again.

Comment: @BoBTFish Go for it, if you aren't sure about something.

Comment: well what i wanted was that numbers should be printed with exactly as many digits as needed

Comment: it all depends on your requirement basically.

Comment: then use setprecision and fixed

Comment: Have you got something against using printf and specifying the number of decimal places, eg %.5f ?

Comment: If you find that article a bit heavy going, I find [this series of blog posts](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/float-precision-revisited-nine-digit-float-portability/) gives a good overview with examples you can get your teeth into.

Comment: printf with %.5f would append 0s (1.23 becomes 1.23000)

Comment: um well...i seriously didn't realize my 'requirements' were so extreme
i'm not worried about the precision...i just want a natural representation for the numbers

here's what i meant by 'good':

1.234 should be 1.234 not 1.23400000 or 1.234e+0 etc.
M_PI should be represented with as many digits as available
etc.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/printf) You could use `%g` with precision specifiers..

Comment: yes, %.16llg does seem to work

Comment: is there any way cout can mimic %llg? (just curious)

Comment: @JayanthKoushik I don't know format specifiers that well. If you want me to add my comment as an answer, let me know.

Comment: @jt234 not sure really it's not a c++ solution (won't work with stream objects unless i sprintf to a buffer and print the string - ugh)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some decimal numbers just aren't representable exactly in binary. Just as there's no exact decimal representation of `1.0 / 3.0`, there's no exact binary representation for `1.0 / 10.0` (also known as `0.1`).

So for the computer, there's no clear notion of "natural representation" or "as many digits as available" in decimal.

When you enter `0.1` into the code, it will actually be represented by the nearest binary value in memory. Converting this binary value back to decimal (which is always possible exactly) yields `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`

Comment: But there is a concept of 'as few digits as are necessary recreate the exact same floating point when read back in'. This does result 1.0/10.0 being printed as 0.1, I think.

Comment: ^ ya that is kinda what i was looking for

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Unfortunately C++ does not provide any such guarantees. Your implementation might do this, but it might not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf or sprintf something like this:

```
float p1 = 1.234;
float p2 = 1.234e-10;
float p3 = M_PI;

printf("%.5g - %.5g - %.5g", p1, p2, p3);
```

output:

```
1,234 - 1,234e-10 - 3,1416
```

Answer (score 1):

C++20 provides [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) that gives you the shortest decimal representation with the round-trip guarantee and the correct rounding:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
  std::cout << std::format("{}\n", M_PI);
  std::cout << std::format("{}\n", 1.234);
  std::cout << std::format("{}\n", 1.234e-10);
}
```

Output:

```
3.141592653589793
1.234
1.234e-10
```

If `std::format` is not yet available in your standard library implementation, you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) it is based on.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Answer (score -1):

implement a method that takes a stream changes it they way you like and outputs it

```
ios_base& myway (ios_base& str){

}
```

Comment: -1. This answer is completely irrelevant to the question. The OP mistakenly expects decimal fractions to be exactly representable in binary floating point formats.

Comment: i know they are not, but maybe he can do something that will detect if the number contains a lot of 0's or 9's and round it, otherwise return it as it is

Comment: But you don't always know if `0.999something` is meant to be `1.0` or not.